# Cause of Exploding NLLLoss

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model

I have been trying to make Transformer based language model, for the loss function Negative Log-likelihood is implemented. For some reason, after a few iterations, there is a steep increase in reconstruction loss.
Here is the log generated by the training program

```
root - WARNING - Loss: 203.81146240234375
root - WARNING - Loss: 124.32596588134766
root - WARNING - Loss: 62.59440612792969
root - WARNING - Loss: 59.84109115600586
root - WARNING - Loss: 59.247005462646484
root - WARNING - Loss: 48.832725524902344
root - WARNING - Loss: 57.592288970947266
root - WARNING - Loss: 50.18443298339844
root - WARNING - Loss: 46.474849700927734
root - WARNING - Loss: 52.12908172607422
root - WARNING - Loss: 50.090736389160156
root - WARNING - Loss: 66.04253387451172
root - WARNING - Loss: 49.094024658203125
root - WARNING - Loss: 36.69044494628906
root - WARNING - Loss: 48.54591369628906
root - WARNING - Loss: 60.71137237548828
root - WARNING - Loss: 40.35478591918945
root - WARNING - Loss: 49.070556640625
root - WARNING - Loss: 54.33742141723633
root - WARNING - Loss: 47.14014434814453
root - WARNING - Loss: 55.043060302734375
root - WARNING - Loss: 47.63726043701172
root - WARNING - Loss: 46.314571380615234
root - WARNING - Loss: 41.330291748046875
root - WARNING - Loss: 48.85242462158203
root - WARNING - Loss: 50.59345245361328
root - WARNING - Loss: 48.508975982666016
root - WARNING - Loss: 43.35681915283203
root - WARNING - Loss: 45.875431060791016
root - WARNING - Loss: 51.701438903808594
root - WARNING - Loss: 39.1783561706543
root - WARNING - Loss: 30.14274024963379
root - WARNING - Loss: 44.33928680419922
root - WARNING - Loss: 40.88005447387695
root - WARNING - Loss: 62.682804107666016
root - WARNING - Loss: 45.18329620361328
root - WARNING - Loss: 39.7137451171875
root - WARNING - Loss: 47.31813049316406
root - WARNING - Loss: 50.755348205566406
root - WARNING - Loss: 40.52918243408203
root - WARNING - Loss: 49.48160934448242
root - WARNING - Loss: 58.29778289794922
root - WARNING - Loss: 45.660675048828125
root - WARNING - Loss: 55.13115692138672
root - WARNING - Loss: 50.72150421142578
root - WARNING - Loss: 33.377098083496094
root - WARNING - Loss: 48.404151916503906
root - WARNING - Loss: 60.24494934082031
root - WARNING - Loss: 46.290470123291016
root - WARNING - Loss: 9.493173539216099e+24
```

After the weight updation of the last iteration, the loss becomes `nan` from that point forth. What are the possible reasons for this to occur ?

Comment: It could be because of exploding gradients, unscaled inputs, or large learning rates. Also, its important to pass log probabilities obtained from a LogSoftmax layer while using NLLLoss. Do check if gradient clipping, learning rate scheduling or changing the optimizer fixes this.

Comment: Yes, the problem stopped existing when I changed my optimizer from Adam to SGD. It is still giving the issue for RMSprop and AdamW

Comment: This could possibly be due to the learning rate schedule then. Using a really low initial learning rate (~ `5e-6`) while using Adam could help verify this.